# Pagination with collection

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm

I have self referential domain like

```
User{

 static hasMany=[friends:User]

}
```

I can get all the friends for a user like this:

```
user.friends
```

But I need to apply pagination where I am running out of idea, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a criteria to retrieve your User objects. Thanks to that, you will be able to use the pagination:

```
int maxElementsPerPage = 15    
User.createCriteria().list(offset: currentPage * maxElementsPerPage, 
                           max: maxElementsPerPage) {
    // condition here
    'in' ('id', user.friends*.id) 
    // I'm not sure if you need to put '*.id'
}
```

You just need to increment the 'currentPage' to have elements for the next page.

For Grails criteria, you should look at the [official Grails criteria documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Or, you can use Grails tag inside a GSP (which will handle everything):

```
<g:paginate controller="user" action="list" total="${userCount}" />
```

More details [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a collection inside your domain class, that you need to paginate, you should make it uni-directional one-to-one:

```
class User {
  static belongsTo = [ friend:User ]
}
```

otherwise GORM will have to cache the `hasMany` id's.

Then the query would be as simple as:

```
def friends = User.findAllByFriend( user, [ max:100, offset:0 ] )
```